# NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermofdel.HSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, android, eclipse, apache-poi

I am new to eclipse/android/java, so please bear with me. I have a couple of apps running so I thought I had grasped some of the concepts but this has stumped me.

I am writing  an android app which references Excel spreadsheets, so I downloaded apache  poi-3.9-20121203.jar and using project/properties/java_build_path/add_external_JARs added poi-3.9.jar to the Referenced libraries tab.

I clicked the poi-3.9 box on the Order and export tab

I hovered and imported over HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); and these are referenced in the import list. No errors in project but when I run it on a Nexus 7 I get the error

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook

The class is listed in the Reference libraries.

I am just starting with excel, and just cut and pasted the code from the tutorial here to get something working:
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/

```
package com.procam.filetest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.RichTextString;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button butCreateSpreadsheet, butEmailFile;
String filename;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    butCreateSpreadsheet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butCreateSpreadsheet);
    butEmailFile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butEmailFile);

    butCreateSpreadsheet.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

// copied code starts here

            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sample sheet");

            Map<String, Object[]> data = new HashMap<String, Object[]>();
            data.put("1", new Object[] {"Emp No.", "Name", "Salary"});
            data.put("2", new Object[] {1d, "John", 1500000d});
            data.put("3", new Object[] {2d, "Sam", 800000d});
            data.put("4", new Object[] {3d, "Dean", 700000d});

            Set<String> keyset = data.keySet();
            int rownum = 0;
            for (String key : keyset) {
                org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
                Object [] objArr = data.get(key);
                int cellnum = 0;
                for (Object obj : objArr) {
                    Cell cell = ((org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row) row).createCell(cellnum++);
                    if(obj instanceof Date) 
                        cell.setCellValue((RichTextString)obj);
                    else if(obj instanceof Boolean)
                        cell.setCellValue((Boolean)obj);
                    else if(obj instanceof String)
                        cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
                    else if(obj instanceof Double)
                        cell.setCellValue((Double)obj);
                }
            }

            try {
                FileOutputStream out = 
                        new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\new.xls"));
                workbook.write(out);
                out.close();
                System.out.println("Excel written successfully..");

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       



//ends here             

        }   
    });


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}



}
```

It looks like to Referenced libraries are not going to the Nexus. I have searched on stackoverflow and found some references to linking referenced libraries to the project but don't understand enough to make sense of them.

Is it a problem with poi-3.9 library not going to the Nexus 7?

Simply explained help much appreciated.

*** Not sure how to update the post, but I rebuilt the Class. This time I added the POI jar files BEFORE the code which referenced them, and it works.

Not sure why this is and don't have time to do the definitive testing, but case closed.

Thanks for help

Comment: you need to add all jar files in POI library along with oxml

Comment: I tried adding all the jar files in the POI download, including those in subdirectories ooxml and lib. I then got the following:[2014-02-04 17:20:25 - FileTest] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.ControlPanel$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. .....etc....